# On which Stack Exchange site should I post this question?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question regarding marriage. I am not able to find the right Stack Exchange site. Please help.

I am 18. I have several points, like I get angry on small things and many more. I will list them. I need advice: Should I marry or live single?

Comment: We need more info. What regarding marriage?

Comment: @Catija I have updated the details. Please see

Comment: Most sites within the SE network rule out personal advice so I doubt you'll find a site that will have that type of question. You might try [Quora](http://quora.com) as they are less strict on what they will accept as questions.

Comment: You need a forum, not a Q&A site. There used to be a relationships site and it failed spectacularly.

Comment: If you google for "relationship advice forums" you'll find a few very large and active ones, choose the one that speaks to you the most. Also consider talking to your peers in real life.

Comment: [You](https://www.quora.com/Should-I-get-married-or-stay-single) [may](https://www.quora.com/Do-you-prefer-to-get-married-or-being-single) [have](https://www.quora.com/Whats-better-being-single-or-getting-married) [more luck with our evil twin](https://www.quora.com/What-is-it-like-to-not-get-married-and-live-alone).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## None of them.

There is currently no SE site that deals with marriage. There is currently an Interpersonal skills  proposal on Area 51 (where new sites are created),but you can't actually post questions there yet. And if/when it goes live, your question probably still won't be able to go there, as... There's no way to answer that question in our format. There is no 'correct'  answer - you'll have to figure it out for yourself. Don't take marriage advice from random people on the Internet :)